# Optimising loops with fixed "if" statements

Tags: php, loops, optimization

I have a PHP function for displaying data in a table which, along with the data itself, also accepts a variable with the fields that should be displayed.

For example, when looking at all the data I want to know the "provider" of each row, but if I'm listing the data related to provider X I don't need the "provider" column.

So I have something like

```
$show['provider'] = true
```

and precede the code outputting the cell with

```
if($show['provider'])
```

However, when there are about 20 different fields and thousands of rows are outputted, this starts to feel hardly optimal, considering every "if" will have the same outcome – it would be enough to execute it once, not once every loop.

One potential solution would be create different code for different listings, but that's terrible for code maintenance. Another would be using `eval()`.

But I'm not sure the risk is worth it even if the data is properly sanitized.

So my question would be twofold:

a) Is there a way to avoid the tens of thousands of "if" statements by preprocessing the code before it's executed?

b) Is it really worth it or are tens of thousands of "ifs" so easy to execute on modern hardware that it's not an issue at all?

Edit: here's an excerpt of code. I'm working with Laravel and this is was generated with the Blade template engine, but since my question isn't limited to Laravel I've edited the code to make it clearer.

```
<!-- foreach($acts as $act) loop -->
    <?php $__currentLoopData = $acts; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $act): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
            <tr data-id="<?php echo e($act->id); ?>">
                <?php if($show['alias']): ?>
                    <td class="dt-alias"><?php echo e($act->getAlias()); ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($show['status']): ?>
                    <td class="dt-status"><?php echo $act->getDisplayStatus(); ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($show['type']): ?>
                    <td class="dt-type"><?php echo e($act->getType()); ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($show['entity']): ?>
                    <td class="dt-entity"><?php echo e($act->getEntity()); ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($show['provider']): ?>
                    <td class="dt-provider"><?php echo e($act->getProvider()); ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- … -->
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with your code so we can help you?

Comment: The real question is should you really be putting thousands of rows in a UI.  Besides that, have you profiled it?  That will tell you whether it's a problem or not.

Comment: This is for an internal data-management platform, and I'm displaying the rows with DataTables for paging, ordering and filtering of data, so displaying thousands of rows of data is a requirement, even if it's usually on the dozens or hundreds. Regarding profiling, I'm not familiar with the best procedures to do it; the default dev tools display the total load time, but not this particular loop's. I'll look into it, though!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not much to work with here I'm afraid. Some of this do not answer your question directly, but there are some points that hopefully might help

1. **Normally** you shouldn't render a huge number of records anyway, so performance wise the gain should be less than marginal.
2. If for some strange reason you need to go full performance then you would you could use a class that avoid those *thousands* of IFs being executed, if you have php72 you may use method overriding giving you the chance to write function for each case. *Although you will have as much functions as combinations are possible, which are exponencial.*
3. Using a bool variable directly instead of $show['something'] would improve performance a bit, depending on how many thousands you have.
4. Having php7.x would drastically improve performance, if you haven't already.
5. querying only the ones you need could also improve performance

IMHO, that if is hard to avoid, maybe someone else could come with something else.